# Understanding integer sum in C

Tags: c, integer, language-lawyer, integer-overflow

I'm trying to formally understand how additive operators work from the Standard's formal standpoint. There are 2 bullets:

> 4 If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed on them.
>
> 5 The result of the binary +
> operator is the sum of the operands.

Considering the following piece of code

```
unsigned int m = UINT_MAX;
printf("%d\n", m + 1);
```

we have that `UINT_MAX + 1` does not fit the width of `unsigned int` so to represent the result `unsigned int` is not enough. So I found a section describing unsigned integers conversions:

> if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly
> adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be
> represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new
> type.

The new type here is `unsigned int`, but the problem is **what is the old type then**? It cannot be `unsigned int` since the resulting value cannot be represented due to the width of `unsigned int` is too small.

Comment: `unsigned int` requires you to use `%u`, not `%d`. And you are not looking at a conversion, but an unsigned overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It cannot be unsigned int since the resulting value cannot be represented due to the width of unsigned int is too small.

That statement is not correct.

*(Quotes below are from the draft standard N1570.)*

The code is adding an `unsigned int` and a `signed int`.

Section 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions describes what happens. The relevant part is:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater **or
> equal to the rank** of the type of the other operand, then **the operand with
> signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
> integer type.**

and 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers tells us

> The rank of any unsigned integer type shall **equal the rank** of the corresponding
> signed integer type, if any.

So these two sections tell that in case of `unsigned-int + signed-int` the signed int will be converted to unsigned int. So in your specific example "the old type" is indeed `unsigned int`.

With respect to the result of the operation Section 6.2.5 Types tells us:

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
> because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
> reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
> represented by the resulting type.

In other words, the result for your code is zero with type `unsigned int`.

So the relevant conversion is in 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
> the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

The old types are `unsigned int` and `int`, `UINT_MAX` and `1` respectively.

The wording quoted describes the mathematical result, and math is not restricted to C types.